# webpack nodejs - Calling an external js file in script tag api call

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, npm, webpack

I am new to nodejs, webpacks and javascripts, looking for assistance.

I have the below project structure using webpack with nodejs:

```
-dist
-node_modules
-public
--test.png
-routes
--web
---usage.html
--api
---testapi.js
-src
--app.js
-index.html
-package-lock.json
-package.json
-webpack.config.js
```

webpack.config.js has this structure:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    main: './src/app.js',
  },

output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".css"]
  },

 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      //other rules
    ]
  },
 devServer: {
    client: {
      overlay: true
    },
    hot: true,
    watchFiles: ['src/*', 'index.html'],
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: ['index.html']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'usage.html',
      template: 'routes/web/usage.html',
    }),
  //other plugins
  ]
};
```

In testapi.js I have a api call using axios :

**testapi.js:**

```
const axios = require('axios');
var temp;

const config = {
    //some_config
};

axios.get(some_url, config)
    .then(async result => {
        temp = result.data;
        console.log("Results: " + JSON.stringify(temp))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

In **usage.html** I am calling the **testapi.js** script (also to cors issue as testapi.js is from a external api) and doing some actions as follows:

**usage.html :**

```
//other scripts
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $.getScript("testapi.js", async function (result) {
             //some logic goes here
       });
    </script>
//body follows
```

**package.json :**

```
{
    "name": //some_app_name,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": //some_desc,
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
        "async": "^3.2.4",
        "aws-amplify": "latest",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "express": "^4.18.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.24.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
        "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "html-webpack-partials-plugin": "^0.8.0",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
        "build": "webpack",
        "prestart": "npm run build",
        "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server --mode development"
    }
}
```

I have tried the below things and nothing seems to be working:

1. Adding the js file as entry // The api gets called in console but with cors issue and not sure how i can use it in usage.html.
2. Added plugin in webpack config with :

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: ['routes/api/testapi.js']
    }),
```

When I do this, I can see the raw code instead of the api response output in Network tab when I load that usage.html page.

3. Used $get instead of $getScript in usage.html.
4. Tried moving testapi to src as well and making necessary changes.

Kindly assist me with this